# Redshift - SQL Left Join does not work with correlated subquery and aggregated function

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, amazon-redshift

I am quite new to Redshift SQL and have been trying to figure out what's wrong with my syntax.

My task is to join 2 tables: `question` and `user` via left join as I want to retain all values from table `question`.

At the moment it throws the following error message: `[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported yet;` when I use `left join`. On the other hand, when I change the code to `join` it works just fine. I suspect this is because I have an aggregated function and logical expression within my subquery that makes my left join an inner join.

But as I mentioned above, I need to retain all values from table `question`.

Below is my code

```
select
qa.user_id as user_email,
i.timestamp as session_login_time,
qa.timestamp as question_ask_time,
qa.question_id,
qa.question
from 
schema1.question as qa
left join
schema1.user as i
on
    qa.user_id = i.email
and 
    i.timestamp =
        (select
            max(timestamp)
         from schema1.user
         where
            timestamp <= qa.timestamp)
where user_email <> 'tester' and user_email not like '%tester.com'
group by qa.user_id, i.timestamp, qa.timestamp, qa.question_id, qa.question
```

The purpose of the subquery is to get the closest `session_login_time` to each of the `question_ask_time`. So, multiple rows of `question` can have the same `session_login_time` value.

Could anybody please help me identify what I am missing from my code above? How do I make my left join works?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually, if I take out the second join criteria (the one that contains a subquery) and put it after my where statement in the end, would that work? - I can't test it now, just want to get your opinion

Comment: If you want rows composed from a row from each table where two columns are related in some way, that is a `join` `on`. Also if you want a value to be one of any in a subselect, that is an `in`. You can google re replacing join, in, scalar subqueries & exists by each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that should get you the same results without involving a sub query

```
select
    qa.user_id as user_email,
    max(i.timestamp) as session_login_time,
    qa.timestamp as question_ask_time,
    qa.question_id,
    qa.question
from schema1.question as qa
left join schema1.user as i
on qa.user_id = i.email
and i.timestamp  <= qa.timestamp
where qa.user_id <> 'tester' and qa.user_id not like '%tester.com'
group by qa.user_id, qa.timestamp, qa.question_id, qa.question
```